# Filter dataframe on time period based on time condition of certain users

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that contains actions done by multiple users at different time periods

```
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:19
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:20
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:21
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:22
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:23
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:51
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:52
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:53
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:53
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:54
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:43
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:44
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:45
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:46
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:47
```

I have another dataframe with certain users that have done some actions at given time.

```
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:53
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:21
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:45
so on
```

Can I filter in the first dataframe the actions of users before or after the time of each one?
In this example the first user should have only the first 2 occurences in the first dataframe if I want to see his actions before the given action.

For example, if I want to have the actions of all users before their respective certain actions, my dataframe would look like this:

```
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:19
user 2   2020-05-04 14:07:20
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:51
user 1   2021-07-19 18:13:52
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:43
user 3   2021-02-03 01:08:44
```

Comment: Can you show the ends result or may be what you are trying so far?

Comment: you can merge the dataframes on both columns and then run  you filter on the time frame you want either before or after.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that there would be a given date for each user. I want to filter the dataframe based on all users, not just for any of them.

Comment: @KarnKumar I have edited my question, so it can be clearer what my outcome would be.